# Problem with two tables of variations :

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

I'm having a hard time making these two tables of variations, I've tried to read Mungus's documentation, but my french is very basic, anyhow I managed to create this but it's not as I expected can you guys help me, and explain to me why this command `\tkzTabIma` takes in arguments exactly because it doesn't work as I will mention in my code

These are the tables I wish to create :

[image]

My attempt to create the first one :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsmfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]%
{$x$/1,$P_n'(x)$/1, $P_n(x)$/2}{$-\infty$,$0$,$x_{n_0}$, 1, $x_{n_1}$, $\dots$, $2k$}%
\tkzTabLine{,+,,+, 0, -, , -, , ,  $\dots$, +}%
\tkzTabVar{- /$-\infty$ , R/,+/, R /, - / , }
\tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{0}
\tkzTabIma{1}{3}{4}{0} %why is this not going to third row as it should ?
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result :

[image]

Comment: Try \tkzTabIma{3}{5}{4}{0}
--> the first parameter      : 3 is rank of the origin of the arrow
--> the second parameter : 5 is rank of the end of the arrow

Answer (score 1):

This code does not use `\tkzTabIma`.

Using `\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5, help]` will display the name of the nodes.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]%
    {$x$/1,$P_n'(x)$/1, $P_n(x)$/2}{$-\infty$,$0$,$x_{n_0}$, 1, $x_{n_1}$, $\dots$, $2k$}%
    \tkzTabLine{,+,,+, 0, -, , -, , ,  $\dots$, +}%
    \tkzTabVar{- /$-\infty$ , R/,+/, R /, - / , }
    \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{$0$}
%   \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{4}{0} %why is this not going to third row as it should ?
    \path (N42)--node[midway,fill=white]{$0$}(N43);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1)... Thanks for the remark, but I guess that's just a comment since it doesn't fully solve my problem which is the actual table